# Get users that have "x" in firebase database in android studio

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I put data in realtime database like this:

[image]

And I want FOR EVERY user (in this case KXya0 ...) to get "zile" 
I have this code

```
databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        if (dataSnapshot.exists() && dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount() > 0) {
            String day = dataSnapshot.child("ck").child("zile").getValue().toString();
            Toast.makeText(CalendarClienti.this, day, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onCancelled (DatabaseError databaseError){


    }
});
```

I know that i need to say smth like child(user).child("zile") etc.. But I want to do it for all the users. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reference your query to **Agenti** and then iterate through each user to get **zile** like below:

```
DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Agenti");
databaseReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot childSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            if (childSnapshot.exists() && childSnapshot.getChildrenCount() > 0) {
                String day = childSnapshot.child("ck").child("zile").getValue().toString();
                Toast.makeText(CalendarClienti.this, day, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

Comment: this work fine, but for every user that have this path "ck/zile" I want to get "do" from database. Can I do that?

Comment: Use `childSnapshot.child("do").getValue().toString();` to get **do**